# setState in React: How to create a variable the value for which is dependent on another variable's value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I'm using React to build an application which performs a number of calculations, provided with some form input from the user. I'm looking to create quite a few variables, the value of each will be dependent on the user's input. However, I'm unsure what syntax is required to identify the value of another specific variable when defining a new variable's value using setState.

For example, the application asks the user to input their daily contract rate and annual expenses claimed into a form. The first calculation that I want to make is a rough estimation of the user's annual gross income, which would be the contract rate multiplied by 220 working days. Currently, my function for updating the variable values looks like this:

```
handleInputChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
        rate: event.target.value,
        expenses: event.target.value,
        annualFees: rate.value * 220
    })
}
```

The syntax assigning the value to 'annualFees' is obviously incorrect, but it demonstrates what I'm trying to achieve. Can somebody explain the correct code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you update the annualFees state variable once the rate has been updated using the second argument of the `setState` method like this?

```
handleInputChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
        rate: event.target.value
    }, () => {
        this.setState({
            annualFees: this.state.rate * 220
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `switch` statement in your `handleInputChange()` method.

```
handleInputChange = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  switch (event.target.name) {
    case 'rate':
      this.setState({
        rate: event.target.value,
        annualFees: event.target.value * 220
      });
      break;
    case 'expenses':
      this.setState({
        expenses: event.target.value
      });
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
};
```

And you can *destructure* your variables like this: `const { name, value } = event.target;` just above your `switch` statement to improve your code's readability.

**NOTE:** With this you would need to add the *name* attribute to your `<input />` tags. e.g

```
<input
  type="number"
  name="rate"
  value={this.state.rate}
  onChange={e => handleInputChange(e)}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I like the idea of using a switch statement, and this would work perfectly for most of the variables that I want to create, but it looks as though it would prevent me from calculating variables where the value is derived from the input for both rate and expenses. For example, if I want to calculate the total taxable income, which would be rate * 220 - expenses. Do you have any idea how this might be achieved?

Comment: Sure, a simple case would be that you calculate it with your _second_ input field and get the other from `this.state`. But of course, this could differ with your particular scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't store `annualFees` in State because according to [React Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-3-identify-the-minimal-but-complete-representation-of-ui-state): `State` should be minimal representation of UI state.

So, you can store `rate` in state and create a function for calculating `annualFees`. This way your state will be minimal.

```
handleInputChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
        rate: event.target.value,
   })
}

calculateAnnualFees = () => {
 const { rate } = this.state;
 return rate*220;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example something like this

```
    const rate = Number(event.target.value);

    this.setState({
        rate,
        expenses: rate,
        annualFees: rate * 220
```

EDIT: although, if `annualFees` is strictly tied to `rate`, then rather keep only `rate` in the state, and compute `annualFees` when needed (so, replace all your `this.state.annualFees` with `220 * this.state.rate`, maybe write a selector-like function: `annualFees = () => 220 * this.state.rate`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the question right. You can access the actual value of the state like that:

```js
annualFees: this.state.rate.value * 220 // using the old value of rate
```

else you can do it like that:

```js
handleInputChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
        rate: event.target.value,
        expenses: event.target.value,
        annualFees: event.target.value * 220
    })
}
```